Error response is returned in SWR's data object instead of SWR's error object
I have this axios request to my backend:
export const getData = async (
  url,
  requestBody = null
) => {
  
  try {
    const response =
      newSalesParameters &&
      (await axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url,
        data: { ...requestBody }
      }))
    return response
  } catch (error) {
    throw error.response.data
  }
}

and this is what the error.response.data looks like:
{
  errors: [Object],
  title: 'Es gab einen Validierungsfehler.',
  status: 422
}

this is my handler function from /api/form.js, if I console log, I get the error fine:
async function handler2(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    try {
      const form = await getForm(params?.url, params.requestData)
      if (form.data) {
        return res.status(200).json(form.data)
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return res.status(422).json(e)
    }
    return res.status(404)
  }
}

And the swr call in my custom hook:
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import useSWR from 'swr'

export default function useForm(
...
) {
  const { data, error, isValidating } = useSWR(
   conditionMet
      ? [
          '/api/form',
          {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
         ...
            })
          },
          requestData
        ]
      : null,
    {
      revalidateIfStale: false,
      revalidateOnFocus: false,
      revalidateOnReconnect: false,
      revalidateOnMount: true,
      suspense: true,
      keepPreviousData: true
    }
  )

  if (groupId === 'rating' && formId === 'simple') {
    return {
      ratingForm: data,
      isRatingFormLoading: isValidating,
      isRatingFormError: error
    }
  }
  console.log('======> THIS ERROR IS ALWAYS UNDEFINED', error)
  return {
    form: data,
    isFormLoading: isValidating,
    isFormError:
      (error || !formId || !groupId || !data || data.errors) && !isValidating
  }
}

I am able to get the error in the component if I return it as data, but as I've highlighted in my console log, I am unable to get the error from the SWR request. The request produces a 422 error in the browser.
Does anyone know why I am unable to catch this error? I can console log it everywhere until this point, but I have no success trying to catch it here.
Thanks in advance!

Are you using App Router or pages router ?

@Beast80K Good point, I should have mentioned that - we are still using Pages router

Please check out the below solution OR did you find any solution?

Problem :

I am able to get the error in the compoennt if I return it as data, but as I've highlighted in my console log, I am unable to get the error from the SWR request.

What I Understood :

So error is retuned is in SWR's data object, & error object in SWR is empty

Possible Cause :

Try Catch in fetcher function (yours getData ).

Possible Solution :
Don't use try-catch, just keep it simple, as you are using axios :
export const getData = async (
  url,
  requestBody = null
) => {
    const response =
      newSalesParameters &&
      (await axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url,
        data: { ...requestBody }
      }))
    return response.data
  
}

I had used try-catch in my fetcher function errors were returned in data object of swr, after removing try-catch error was returned in error object of SWR

If you have any doubts, then please leave a comment (I will update answer if necessary)


SWR Response contains an error property that catches any thrown errors from the fetcher for you. since you are catching the errors in your fetcher and return them instead of throwing, then SWR will never know you had an error. Simple mistake.
BTW, if SWR receives (key, fetcher config). if you pass {suspense:true} to that config, then SWR will stop catching your errors. You will still have the error in the error property but it will be thrown again. As explained by the docs, when you use suspense mode, you should be wrapping it with a suspense element AND an error boundary, unless you don't mind your app crashing. This only applies for suspense mode though! otherwise SWR catches your errors and they will be available in the error property alongside data, isLoading, etc...

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
